# Writing my First Grease Monkey Script. How do I get innerHTML to use 'contains'?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, reddit

I'm basing it on another script as, although I'm somewhat familiar with javascript, I'm still learning.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           click all "load more" prompts
// @namespace      none
// @include        http://www.reddit.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout('var deleted = 0;var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");var i = 0;var d = 0;for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {var l = links[i];if (l.href) {if (l.innerHTML == "load more comments") {toggle(l);   d = 1;  } } } , 4000);
```

Now, the problem seems to be that none of the innerHTM just says "load more comments."

Instead, it says something like, "load more comments (x replies)" where x can be any number.

Is there a simple way to check and see if the innerHTML contains the term "load more comments" rather than checking for exact equivalence?

Here is a page with the "load more comments" links I'm referring to: http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/g4c8a/whats_the_funniest_thing_you_have_heard_that_you/

Edit:

Here is the updated script.  Doesn't seem to run though, any advice?

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var l = links[i];
    if (l.href){
        if (l.innerHTML.indexOf("load more comments") > -1) {
            toggle(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is JavaScript and innerHTML is a string you can just use a JS string method for this. The traditional way is `indexOf`

```
if(l.innerHTML.indexOf("load more comments") > -1){
   // substring found
}
```

Less traditionally you can use regular expression, or other methods.

I recommend perusing Mozilla's [String documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for details.

EDIT: That looks fine. However, I also recommend that you don't do what you're doing the way you're doing it. Doing anything in JavaScript without using a JS library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) is ridiculously painful, even if it's something simple.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('a').each(function(i){
        if(this.href && this.innerHTML.indexOf('load more comments') > -1){
            toggle(this);
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

Learn jQuery, you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: I edited the original question with updated code -- how that that look?